# python 3.5 numpy+mkl installation error

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to install numpy+mkl for python 3.5.2 but get the following error. Is there a way to fix this? Could the old numpy version be broken?

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip3 install C:\Users\CTX383\Downloads\numpy-1.12.1+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
    Processing c:\users\CTX383\downloads\numpy-1.12.1+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
    Installing collected packages: numpy
      Found existing installation: numpy 1.12.0
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\CTX383\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 209, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "c:\users\CTX383\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 317, in run
        prefix=options.prefix_path,
      File "c:\users\CTX383\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 726, in install
        requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
      File "c:\users\CTX383\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 699, in uninstall
        for path in pip.wheel.uninstallation_paths(dist):
      File "c:\users\CTX383\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 533, in unique
        for item in fn(*args, **kw):
      File "c:\users\CTX383\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 552, in uninstallation_paths
        r = csv.reader(FakeFile(dist.get_metadata_lines('RECORD')))
      File "c:\users\CTX383\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1624, in get_metadata_lines
        return yield_lines(self.get_metadata(name))
      File "c:\users\CTX383\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1621, in get_metadata
        return self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info, name)).decode("utf-8")
      File "c:\users\CTX383\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1727, in _get
        with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\CTX383\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy-1.12.0.dist-info\\RECORD'
    You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: upgrade pip, and please read an error message first.

Comment: @user3483676  try pip3 install --upgrade pip ;
pip2 install --upgrade pip

Comment: another solution is to install the anaconda package https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: I made a complete anaconda update but still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Open your `CMD` with Administrator Privilege.

Then,

`mkdir c:\\users\\CTX383\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy-1.12.0.dist-info`

Then type what ever you was trying to do.

Comment: Now I created the directory but get permission error now although I started cmd with admin privileges.